# Saving form data to local storage and show it on refresh

Tags: jquery, html, local-storage

I am making a form where users can input their data. I'd like for this date to be saved by use of local storage. But when i refresh the page only height and weight are still remembered. And i have been quite stuck on trying to make gender , sportivity and birthdate be remembered as well.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0rc2/jquery.mobile-1.0rc2.min.css" />
    <title>Test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0rc2/jquery.mobile-1.0rc2.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $(window).unload(saveSettings);
            loadSettings();
        });

        function loadSettings() {
            $('#height').val(localStorage.height);
            $('#weight').val(localStorage.weight);
            $('#dateOfBirth').val(localStorage.dateOfBirth);
            $('input[type=radio]:checked').val(localStorage.gender);
            $("#sportive").find("option[value=" + localStorage.sportive + "]").attr("selected", "selected");
        }

        function saveSettings() {
            var height = document.getElementById("height").value;
            var weight = document.getElementById("weight").value;
            var sportive = document.getElementById("sportive").value;
            var gender = $('input[type=radio]:checked').val();
            var dateOfBirth = document.getElementById("dateOfBirth").val();

            localStorage.height = height;
            localStorage.weight = weight;
            localStorage.dateOfBirth = dateOfBirth;
            localStorage.sportive = sportive;
            localStorage.gender = gender;
        }


    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div data-role="content">

        <form id="myForm" >

            gender:

            <input id="man" type="radio" name="gender" value="Man" >
            <label for="man">Man</label>

            <input id="vrouw" type="radio" name="gender" value="Vrouw">
            <label for="vrouw" >Vrouw</label>

            dateOfBirth:
            <input type="date" id="dateOfBirth" name="datum" required />

            weight (in kg):
            <input type="number" id="weight" name="weight" required />

            height (in cm):
            <input type="number" id="height" name="height" required />

            Hoeveel keer doe je aan sport per week?
            <select id="sportive" name="sport">
                <option value="1.2" >Weinig of geen training, kantoorwerk</option>
                <option value="1.375">Lichte training/sport 1-3 dagen per week</option>
                <option value="1.55" >Gemiddelde training/sport 3-5 dagen per week</option>
                <option value="1.725" >Zware training/sport 6-7 dagen per week</option>
                <option value="1.9" >Zware dagelijkse training/sport plus lichamelijk werk</option>
            </select>

            <br />

        </form>

    </div>
</body>
```

greetings

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You are complicating your script. Try this. Working **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/zrsoc16s/)**

If you are using jQuery once, do not mix it with pure javascript, like `document.getElementById()`. And do not create a `height` variable to store the `$('#height').val()`, you can use this directly. Code is more readable.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).unload(saveSettings);
    loadSettings();
});

function loadSettings() {
    $('#height').val(localStorage.height);
    $('#weight').val(localStorage.weight);
    $('#dateOfBirth').val(localStorage.dateOfBirth);
    $('input[value="' + localStorage.gender + '"]').prop('checked', true);
    $("#sportive").val(localStorage.sportive);
}

function saveSettings() {
    localStorage.height = $('#height').val();
    localStorage.weight = $('#weight').val();
    localStorage.dateOfBirth = $('#dateOfBirth').val();
    localStorage.sportive = $("#sportive").val();
    localStorage.gender = $('input[type=radio]:checked').val();
}
```

Update: If you are using jQuery 3, unload will throw an error. You should use this instead:

```
$(window).on('unload', function(){
    saveSettings();
    loadSettings();
});
```