# After refresh page load don't want to remove text box value.

Tags: javascript, html, validation

I have a form which contain LAN number which is numeric value.

I want to keep this text box value after refresh page load.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31311121/retaining-the-textbox-values-even-after-refresh

Comment: Without using LocalStorage, have you test with `Autocomplete="on"` html attribute ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use either `sessionStorage` or `localStorage` to save input value at some point to storage and retrieve it on page load. Please see below snippet:

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  var inp = document.getElementById('ip');
  var storedUserIp = document.sessionStorage.getItem('userIp');
  inp.value = storedUserIp || "";
  inp.addEventListener("change", function() {
    document.sessionStorage.setItem('userIp', inp.value);
  });
});
```

```html
<input id="ip" />
```

More about storages:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage